# Limit of accumulation points

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a set and, for each $n$, $x_n$ is an accumulation point of $S$. Suppose further that $\lim_{n}x_{n}=x$.  Prove that $x$ is also an accumulation point of S.

I was given the hints that: It is not stated that $x_n \in S$ or that $x \in S$.  Approach this by the definition, i.e. For every $\epsilon > 0$, you need to fine $u \in S$ such that $0 < |u - x|<\epsilon$.  $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is an important feature.

I was unsure if this was true because couldn't I have (-$\infty$, y) where y is some arbitrary element.  Then everything leading up to y would be an accumulation point, but the limit, being y, wouldn't be an accumulation point. Assuming that this statement is true, I don't know where to begin.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you think $y$ isn't an accumulation point of $(-\infty,y)$?

Comment: A more general fact (for which proofs can be found on this site) is the fact that the set of accumulation points of $S$ is closed. In particular closed under sequential limits.

Comment: Oh, I though there had to be something greater than y for it to be an accumulation point, but the boundary is also one because there is a neighbor less than y.  So y is an accumulation point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon >0$ and choose, for each $n\in \mathbb N$ an $x'_n\in S$ such that $\vert x'_n-x_n \vert <\frac{\epsilon }{2}$. This is possible because each $x_n$ is an accumulation point of $S$.

We may also assume that $x'_n\neq x$, since if $x$ were the only point from $S$ in $B(x_n,\epsilon /2)$ different from $x_n$ then $B(x_n,\frac{\vert x-x_n\vert }{2})\cap S=\emptyset $, a contradiction.

Now, by hypothesis there is an $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $n>N\Rightarrow \vert x_n-x\vert<\frac{\epsilon }{2}$ so that we have

$\vert x'_n-x\vert\leq \vert x'_n-x_n\vert +\vert x_n-x\vert=\frac{\epsilon }{2}+\frac{\epsilon }{2}=\epsilon.$ and the claim follows.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Thanks for pointing this out. I took care of it.